# Continuously getting error in spark-submit job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am continuously getting this error:

```
16/02/29 14:49:40 WARN BlockManager: Block input-0-1456737579500 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
```

while running the spark-submit job.

```
./spark-submit --jars jar_names--driver-class-path --packages --executor-memory 6g --executor-cores 4 --master local[4] script.py
```

I am getting this error as soon as it is started: Error says:

```
WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
WARN Utils: Your hostname, host_name resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using ip instead (on interface eth0) 
WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
```

I have also tried using `--master[4]` but still getting the error.

Comment: Please describe full problem

Comment: Its local machine. 
 
   ./spark-submit --jars jar_names--driver-class-path --packages --executor-memory 6g --executor-cores 4 --master local[4] script.py

I am getting this error as soon as it is started:
Error says:

WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
WARN Utils: Your hostname, host_name resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using ip instead (on interface eth0)
WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address

Comment: Those seem to be warnings. Are you not getting any other errors?

Comment: You can ignore these warnings, your job should be working fine if there are no further errors.